# Match a unix line ending with grep

Tags: bash, unix, grep, pcre, line-endings

How can I match a unix line ending with grep? I already have a working script that uses `unix2dos` and `cmp`, but it's a bit slow, and a single grep command would fit in a lot better with the rest of my bash code.

I tried using a negative lookbehind on `'\r'`.

```
$ printf "foo\r\n" | grep -PUa '(?<!'$'\r'')$'
foo
```

Why doesn't that work? For the record, the regex pattern seems to evaluate just well this way:

```
$ printf '(?<!'$'\r'')$' | od -a
0000000   (   ?   <   !  cr   )   $
0000007
```

Update:

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.24
```

on MINGW64 on windows 7.

Comment: If you need to match a newline not preceded with `\r`, just use `'(?<!\r)\n'`

Comment: `printf "foo\n" | grep -PUa '(?<!\r)\n'` shows no match

Comment: *Why doesn't that work?* Works for me with `grep (GNU grep) 2.25`

Comment: @Leon so it shows no match for you, while `$ printf "foo\n" | grep -PUa '(?<!'$'\r'')$'` does?

Comment: Yes, exactly (some silly text enforced by the limit on a shortest comment length)

Comment: Do you really need this to work with `grep -P`? If not, please edit the title.

Comment: No, I don't need that, but I was wondering why it wouldn't work. Will update title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution with `grep -PUa '(?<!'$'\r'')$'` worked with a more recent version of grep (2.25). However the support for Perl-compatible regular expression (`-P`) is stated to be highly experimental even in that newer version of grep, so it's not surprising that it didn't work in the previous version.

Use the following basic regular expression: `\([^\r]\|^\)$`, i.e. the following `grep` command when running from `bash`:

```
grep -Ua '\([^'$'\r'']\|^\)$'
```

An example demonstrating that it correctly handles both empty and non-empty lines:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\r\n\nx\n\r\ny\nbaz\n" | grep -Ua '\([^'$'\r'']\|^\)$'
foo

x
y
baz
$
```

**EDIT**

The solution above treats the last line *not including an end-of-line symbol* as if it ended with a unix line ending. E.g.

```
$ printf "foo\nbar" | grep -Ua '\([^'$'\r'']\|^\)$'
foo
bar
```

That can be fixed by appending an artificial CRLF to the input - if the input ends with a newline, then the extra (empty) line will be dropped by `grep`, otherwise it will make `grep` to drop the last line:

```
$ { printf "foo\nbar"; printf "\r\n"; } | grep -Ua '\([^'$'\r'']\|^\)$'
foo
$
```

Comment: It doesn't work when there is text but no line endings: it will still match, even when there are no unix line endings